# Pragma reordered by cpp

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have observed a strange behaviour in cpp when dealing with pragmas and macros: it moves these directives from their actual line to the beginning of the macro expansion.

Example:

```
#define K( arg ) arg

K(
    int a = 0;

    #pragma unroll
    for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
        a++;
    }
)
```

The output:

```
#pragma unroll
int a = 0; for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) { a++; }
```

What is the cause of this? Is there any way to keep the pragma in place?
Please, abstain from suggesting using sed or something similar, I want to solve this with just the preprocessor.

Comment: If anything is going to do it, using the [§6.10.9 Pragma operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.9) —  `_Pragma("unroll")` — is probably the way to do it.  You can't embed other preprocessing directives, such as `#if` and `#endif`, inside the body of a macro either.  However, a quick experiment showed that `gcc -E` still put `#pragma` before the expanded loop.  You might need to check whether the pragma takes effect by looking at the assembler code.  An optimizer might change that particular loop to `a = 5;`, eliminating `i` altogether, and not unrolling anything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is just sample code. You can assume K will contain more complex code in the future. The resulting code could be fed to compilers different from gcc, so the preprocessing step must be completely independent.

Comment: The [GCC Loop-Specific Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Loop-Specific-Pragmas.html#Loop-Specific-Pragmas) documentation says you need to use `#pragma GCC unroll n` (specifying how many times to unroll the loop).

Comment: You cannot possibly rely on any `#pragma` that is not documented by the standard being portable to any compiler.  Pragmas are inherently compiler specific.  There are 3 standard pragmas, all starting `#pragma STDC` — none of them is related to loop unrolling.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's not a problem, code that contains #pragma unroll will be targeted at a specific compiler. We could say this is the only compiler is causing me any trouble due to pragmas, precisely.

Comment: I tried various ways of doing it with variations on the theme of `#pragma GCC unroll 5`.  None affected the code when no optimization was used; using `-O` (no qualifiers) replaced the sample code with `return 5;` when the invocation of `K` was placed inside `int main(void) {` and `return a; }`.  This probably means the sample code is too minimal for the effect of loop unrolling to be demonstrable.  (See also [§6.10.6 Pragma directive](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.6) for the standard pragmas, and documentation of "it's all compiler dependent".)

Comment: Fitting the sample code between ```int main(void) {``` and ```return a;}``` will still reorder the pragma, though. As it is correct code I don't see why the preprocessor should behave like that. I must give support for codes as simple as this as well, so overlooking this just because a more complex code works is not admissible.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Transferring selected comments into an answer, and expanding the information…*</sup>

If anything is going to do it, using the [§6.10.9 Pragma operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.9) — `_Pragma("unroll")` — is probably the way to do it. You can't embed other preprocessing directives, such as `#if` and `#endif`, inside the body of a macro invocation either. However, a quick experiment showed that `gcc -E` still put `#pragma` before the expanded loop. You might need to check whether the pragma takes effect by looking at the assembler code. An optimizer might change that particular loop to `a = 5;`, eliminating `i` altogether, and not unrolling anything.

Additionally, the [GCC Loop-Specific Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Loop-Specific-Pragmas.html#Loop-Specific-Pragmas) documentation says you need to use `#pragma GCC unroll n` (specifying how many times to unroll the loop).

You cannot possibly rely on any `#pragma` that is not documented by the standard being portable to any compiler. Pragmas are inherently compiler-specific. There are 3 standard pragmas, all starting `#pragma STDC` — none of them is related to loop unrolling.  See also [§6.10.6 Pragma directive](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.6) for the standard pragmas, and documentation of "it's all compiler dependent".

Making the code in the loop a little more complex, you can get the loop unrolled if you use:

- `_Pragma("GCC unroll 5")`

It does not work if you try:

- `#pragma GCC unroll 5`

Sample code:

```
extern double course_deviation(double x, double y);
#define K( arg ) arg

int main(void)
{
K(
    int a = 0;
    _Pragma("GCC unroll 5")
    //#pragma GCC unroll 5
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a += course_deviation(i + 3.0, i - 3.0);
    }
)
    return a;
}
```

With `#pragma` directive exposed instead of the `_Pragma` operator, the code doesn't compile.  As shown, the relevant section of the assembler code produced by GCC 9.3.0 on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 is:

```
$ gcc -O -S k37.c
$ sed '/LFE0/q' k37.s
        .text
        .section __TEXT,__text_startup,regular,pure_instructions
        .globl _main
_main:
LFB0:
        subq    $24, %rsp
LCFI0:
        movsd   lC0(%rip), %xmm1
        movsd   lC1(%rip), %xmm0
        call    _course_deviation
        movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)
        movsd   lC2(%rip), %xmm1
        movsd   lC3(%rip), %xmm0
        call    _course_deviation
        movapd  %xmm0, %xmm1
        pxor    %xmm2, %xmm2
        addsd   8(%rsp), %xmm2
        cvttsd2sil      %xmm2, %eax
        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
        cvtsi2sdl       %eax, %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)
        movsd   lC5(%rip), %xmm1
        movsd   lC6(%rip), %xmm0
        call    _course_deviation
        movapd  %xmm0, %xmm1
        cvttsd2sil      8(%rsp), %eax
        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
        cvtsi2sdl       %eax, %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)
        pxor    %xmm1, %xmm1
        movsd   lC7(%rip), %xmm0
        call    _course_deviation
        movapd  %xmm0, %xmm1
        cvttsd2sil      8(%rsp), %eax
        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
        cvtsi2sdl       %eax, %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        movsd   %xmm0, 8(%rsp)
        movsd   lC8(%rip), %xmm1
        movsd   lC9(%rip), %xmm0
        call    _course_deviation
        movapd  %xmm0, %xmm1
        cvttsd2sil      8(%rsp), %eax
        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
        cvtsi2sdl       %eax, %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        cvttsd2sil      %xmm0, %eax
        addq    $24, %rsp
LCFI1:
        ret
LFE0:
```

Without the `-O` option (no optimization), the relevant section of the assembler code is as follows — no loop unrolling.  It appears that loop unrolling is an optimization — no optimization, no loop unrolling.

```
        .text
        .globl _main
_main:
LFB0:
        pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
        movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
        jmp     L2
L3:
        cvtsi2sdl       -8(%rbp), %xmm0
        movsd   lC0(%rip), %xmm1
        movapd  %xmm0, %xmm2
        subsd   %xmm1, %xmm2
        cvtsi2sdl       -8(%rbp), %xmm1
        movsd   lC0(%rip), %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        movapd  %xmm2, %xmm1
        call    _course_deviation
        cvtsi2sdl       -4(%rbp), %xmm1
        addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
        cvttsd2sil      %xmm0, %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        addl    $1, -8(%rbp)
L2:
        cmpl    $4, -8(%rbp)
        setle   %al
        testb   %al, %al
        jne     L3
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        leave
LCFI2:
        ret
LFE0:
```

I tried using `atan2()` from `<math.h>` in place of the `course_correction()` function, and the optimizer optimized the code to — simply returning `7`:

```
        .text
        .section __TEXT,__text_startup,regular,pure_instructions
        .globl _main
_main:
LFB19:
        movl    $7, %eax
        ret
LFE19:
```

With the original code (`a++;` in the loop body, the result was returning `5` instead of `7`.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort. This is undoubtedly interesting, but it doesn't actually address my problem. Maybe I wasn't explicit enough. What I need is the output of cpp (or gcc -E if you will) keeps the pragma in place. The output will be later fed to a specific compiler that supports ```#pragma unroll```. The reason for doing this is the preprocessor of that compiler poses additional problems when including certain headers in my program files that must be indeed included for the sake of my objective. It may sound weird but I cannot tell more for secrecy reasons.

Comment: AFAIK — there's nothing you can do — you'll have to fall back on something like `sed` after all to post-process what the preprocessor produces.  You're stuck with what the compilers do; you can either revise the compiler source code to do what you want (which is kinda hard), or you can deal with what it produces in whatever way you think most appropriate.  It will be tough to deal with the way the `#pragma` is put into the `-E` output in general.  You might use a pseudo-function call in the macro — `generate_pragma_here(unroll)` for example, and then edit that into what you want.